# Electron (Atom-Shell) Run unix command from link in page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, command, electron

I am trying to learn Electron (Atom-Shell) but I am finding it pretty tough to find documentation for it...

I am simply trying to figure out how to create a link with `<a href="something"></a>` in index.html, and have it open a terminal window or run some sort of program.

I learn languages by learning specific tasks as I need them in a program, so that is why I am asking so then I can utilize the technique used in other ways in my programs.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, essentially Electron is just a customised version of a Chromium browser that comes packaged with Nodejs and some really cool packages that basically allow you to run the custom browser as if it was a native platform application. Because of that creating an Electron app is very similar to creating a web-app that has a Nodejs back-end.

So to get started with a simple "Hello World!" app, you can just run the following npm...

```
npm install electron-prebuilt --save-dev
```

Once the npm is installed you'll need three files to run an Electron app.

1. A package.json file
2. A javascript file (default is main.js)
3. An html file   (default is index.html)

See this GitHub repo for a quick copy/paste version of each and more detailed instructions: https://github.com/mafintosh/electron-prebuilt

after that you're ready to simply run your app...

```
$ electron .
```

Finally, one way to open a terminal window would be to use an onclick attribute in your html to trigger a child_process, found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), in a function.

That's it! You should be able to edit your html and javascript files as you would for any web-app, and take advantage of the added features that Electron provides.

I'd also check out these resources for more info:

A Quick Start intro to how Electron works -- https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md

The Atom discussion forum (Because Atom was built with Electron, and is made to be hackable, the community is quite active) -- https://discuss.atom.io/c/electron

A cool repo to keep up with the latest info. It includes links for apps that currently use Electron, tutorials, videos, and more --
https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-electron

I hope that helps!